# SpriteKit Detect End of Contact After Detecting Begin of Contact

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

This is what I try to accomplish:

Two sprite nodes in the scene, and self is an edge loop.

If nodeA touches nobeB, and stop. >> Win

If nodeA touches self. >> Lose

If nodeA touches nobeB but didn't stop and touches self. >> Lose

Therefore I need something that works like this:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(aero, SpriteNodeCategory)
{
    SpriteNodeCategoryA    = 1 << 0,
    SpriteNodeCategoryB    = 1 << 1,
};

-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    aero collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);
    if (collision == (SpriteNodeCategoryA|SpriteNodeCategoryB)) {
        //something here I don't know...
    }
    if (collision == (SpriteNodeCategoryA|SpriteNodeCategoryB)) {
        NSLog(@"FAIL");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so this is going to be a little difficult.

First of, you can use "didSimulatePhysics" to get the update of your simulation

```
-(void)didSimulatePhysics
{
    if (_yourNode.physicsBody.angularVelocity == 0 && newGame) {
        if (_yourNode.userData[@"winningCondition"]) {
            [self win];
        };
    }
}
```

this does is that it updates and see if you have a winning condition - which is gotten from collision (think: reverse engineering)

P.S. _yourNode.physicsBody.angularVelocity == 0 meaning your node is completely still

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);
    if (collision == (CNPhysicsCategoryNodeA|CNPhysicsCategoryNodeB)) {
        _yourNode.userData = [@{@"winningCondition":@(YES)} mutableCopy];
    }
    if (collision == (CNPhysicsCategoryNodeA|CNPhysicsCategoryEdge)) {
        [self lose];
    }
}

-(void)didEndContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);
    if (collision == (CNPhysicsCategoryNodeA|CNPhysicsCategoryNodeB)) {
        _yourNode.userData = [@{@"winningCondition":@(NO)} mutableCopy];
    }
}
```

So basically when A touches B, it gives you a winning condition through adding a "userData" to your node.

The rest is pretty straight forward. I think you get it.

Answer (score 2):

You have another method delegate (SKPhysicsContactDelegate) which do the job you asking about:

```
- (void)didEndContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
```

Comment: How do you put it into -(void)didBeginContact: method?

Comment: You don't put it into didBeginContact:, you need to add two method: didBeginContact: to handle action when the contact begin and  didEndContact: for handle action when the contact ended.

Comment: Right, and how do I pass the if statement to the didEndContact?

Comment: I don't know what are you trying to do but, Yes you can pass the if and you can use it as you use didBeginContact: the difference is that the method is called after that.

Comment: How do you pass the if statement between two methods? Can you give a code example?

Comment: You can use ivars to do that, for example you can declare bool isHeroContactBegin, you initialise it with init isHeroContactBegin = NO; and in didBeginContact if the contact begin you change it to YES. In didEndContact you check it isHeroContactBegin == YES and you handle the action after that you reset it to NO. It's difficult to give you an example because I don't know what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: This is what I try to accomplish:

Two sprite nodes in the scene, and self is an edge loop.

If nodeA touches nobeB, and stop. >> Win

If nodeA touches self. >> Lose

If nodeA touches nobeB but didn't stop and touches self. >> Lose

Comment: So you can use boolean ivars as I explained above. You just need more than one variable.